# Python float silent overflow precision error

Tags: python, floating-point, overflow, precision, floating-accuracy

StackOverflow has quite a few topics on the floating point representations, about exceptions, truncation, precision issues. I have been trying to explain this one but still didn't figured it out.

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, div

fun = 'add(add(sub(sub(safeDiv(xL1, add(D, mul(sub(add(sub(A, 0), mul(D, rv)), mul(xL1, add(D, 3))), xL1))), add(0, rv)), safeDiv(mul(sub(D, sigma2), safeDiv(sub(safeDiv(xL1, A), 1), add(safeDiv(safeDiv(B1, xL1), sub(4, xL2)), add(sigma1, xL1)))), sigma1)), add(4, B1)), add(add(A, A), sub(add(xL1, xL1), mul(xL2, safeDiv(xL1, add(sub(add(mul(D, -4), add(add(safeDiv(mul(sigma2, sigma2), safeDiv(B1, sigma1)), sub(add(D, safeDiv(xL2, B1)), D)), sub(4, B1))), A), add(mul(sigma2, xL1), mul(xL1, mul(rv, xL2)))))))))'

d = [(
51.696521954140991,
31.156112806482234,
54.629863633907163,
27.491618858013698,
26.223584534107289,
77.10005191617563,
2708.4145268939428,
0.20952943771134946,
15.558278150405643,
102.0,
225.0)]

arglabels = ['xL1', 'sigma1', 'xL2', 'sigma2', 'A', 'B1', 'D', 'rv']
other = {'add': add, 'sub':sub, 'mul':mul,'safeDiv':div}
inputs = dict(zip(arglabels, d[0][: -4] + (d[0][-3]*d[0][-4],)))
inputs.update(other)
print eval(fun, inputs)
```

This code should produce a result somewhere between 225 and 240, but instead returns a negative number. And that's it, no exception, no warning, nothing. So it must be a precision error somewhere that turns the result completely off.

By rounding the maximum I can use to get a reasonable result is 1 decimal place (And that gets me close to 207...), longdoubles from numpy help in some cases but is not enough. I have done it by hand (so considerable precision loss, and obtained 240).

Another detail, running in the notebook together with the main script I have [this behaviour](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9211023/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-27%20at%2023.06.43.png):

[image]

When I add the locals dictionary for the first time it returns a very plausible result, but the following time it goes back to the negative value. There must be some import affecting this but I cannot find it either.

What should I do to avoid this? How can I get some kind of warning generated? How can I track where it goes wrong?

**EDIT:**  The accepted answer identifies the issue properly, take a look at the comments below the answer for more details. However, it does not discuss how to avoid it or correct the function(s). Maybe that should be a discussion for MathOverflow...

Comment: You can track where it goes wrong by separating the complex function into smaller steps and evaluating each step.  Perhaps split "fun" into 4-6 pieces, depending on what's easy for you to check.  When you find the faulty one, split that further until you eventually find the erroneous operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the expected result is in range `225...240` the following issues are possible:

- an error during generation of `fun`
- incorrect values in `d`
- the functions `add`, `sub`, `mul` and `safeDiv` should do something more complex than just floating point addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

The input provided in the question cannot give anything other than `-2786.17215265`, since it is a perfect numerical result. There is no floating point rounding errors or overflows. Below it is shown by output of the test script with verbose version of the arithmetic functions that all floating point operations are well defined. There is nothing that can give noticeable rounding errors. There are some risky operations when close values are subtracted:

```
add: -10626.8589858 + 10627.794501 = 0.935515251547
```

However, it is far to rounding errors.

The same result can obtained by a C program or in mathematics tools (MATLAB/Octave).

---

The different outputs in the screenshot are due to values of the local variables that are not displayed there. Since `Out[108]` is the same as `Out[110]` I assume that `ds` is the same as `data[17]`. The local variables are used for both outputs `Out[109]` and `Out[110]`, so the difference is in values of `rv`, since only that variable is changed in `In[110]`. If the values of all other variables are fixed it can be seen that the `Out[109]` (`230.62977145178198`) can be obtained if `rv` is equal to one of the following values: `4.075164147`, `4.485709922`, `51.72476610`. That is also illustrated by the last output line in the test script below.

Note that if `fun` is analyzed as a function of `rv` it has two poles (around `3.3` and `51.7`). So, technically the function can give results from minus infinity to plus infinity.

---

> Test

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, div

fun = 'add(add(sub(sub(safeDiv(xL1, add(D, mul(sub(add(sub(A, 0), mul(D, rv)), mul(xL1, add(D, 3))), xL1))), add(0, rv)), safeDiv(mul(sub(D, sigma2), safeDiv(sub(safeDiv(xL1, A), 1), add(safeDiv(safeDiv(B1, xL1), sub(4, xL2)), add(sigma1, xL1)))), sigma1)), add(4, B1)), add(add(A, A), sub(add(xL1, xL1), mul(xL2, safeDiv(xL1, add(sub(add(mul(D, -4), add(add(safeDiv(mul(sigma2, sigma2), safeDiv(B1, sigma1)), sub(add(D, safeDiv(xL2, B1)), D)), sub(4, B1))), A), add(mul(sigma2, xL1), mul(xL1, mul(rv, xL2)))))))))'

d = [(
51.696521954140991,
31.156112806482234,
54.629863633907163,
27.491618858013698,
26.223584534107289,
77.10005191617563,
2708.4145268939428,
0.20952943771134946,
15.558278150405643,
102.0,
225.0)]

def add_verbose(a,b):
    res = a + b;
    print "add: {0} + {1} = {2}".format(a,b,res);
    return res;

def sub_verbose(a,b):
    res = a - b;
    print "sub: {0} - {1} = {2}".format(a,b,res);
    return res;

def div_verbose(a,b):
    res = a / b;
    print "div: {0} / {1} = {2}".format(a,b,res);
    return res;

def mul_verbose(a,b):
    res = a * b;
    print "mul: {0} * {1} = {2}".format(a,b,res);
    return res;

arglabels = ['xL1', 'sigma1', 'xL2', 'sigma2', 'A', 'B1', 'D', 'rv']
other = {'add': add_verbose, 'sub':sub_verbose, 'mul':mul_verbose,'safeDiv':div_verbose}
inputs = dict(zip(arglabels, d[0][: -4] + (d[0][-3]*d[0][-4],)))
inputs.update(other)

# out 108
print eval(fun, inputs)

# set locals that can give out 109
safeDiv = div;
rv = 4.0751641470166795256;
inputs.update(locals());

# out 109
print eval(fun, inputs)
```

> Output

```
sub: 26.2235845341 - 0 = 26.2235845341
mul: 2708.41452689 * 3.25991727261 = 8829.20729761
add: 26.2235845341 + 8829.20729761 = 8855.43088215
add: 2708.41452689 + 3 = 2711.41452689
mul: 51.6965219541 * 2711.41452689 = 140170.700616
sub: 8855.43088215 - 140170.700616 = -131315.269734
mul: -131315.269734 * 51.6965219541 = -6788542.72473
add: 2708.41452689 + -6788542.72473 = -6785834.3102
div: 51.6965219541 / -6785834.3102 = -7.61830006318e-06
add: 0 + 3.25991727261 = 3.25991727261
sub: -7.61830006318e-06 - 3.25991727261 = -3.25992489091
sub: 2708.41452689 - 27.491618858 = 2680.92290804
div: 51.6965219541 / 26.2235845341 = 1.97137511414
sub: 1.97137511414 - 1 = 0.971375114142
div: 77.1000519162 / 51.6965219541 = 1.49139727397
sub: 4 - 54.6298636339 = -50.6298636339
div: 1.49139727397 / -50.6298636339 = -0.029456869265
add: 31.1561128065 + 51.6965219541 = 82.8526347606
add: -0.029456869265 + 82.8526347606 = 82.8231778914
div: 0.971375114142 / 82.8231778914 = 0.0117283004453
mul: 2680.92290804 * 0.0117283004453 = 31.4426693361
div: 31.4426693361 / 31.1561128065 = 1.00919744165
sub: -3.25992489091 - 1.00919744165 = -4.26912233256
add: 4 + 77.1000519162 = 81.1000519162
add: -4.26912233256 + 81.1000519162 = 76.8309295836
add: 26.2235845341 + 26.2235845341 = 52.4471690682
add: 51.6965219541 + 51.6965219541 = 103.393043908
mul: 2708.41452689 * -4 = -10833.6581076
mul: 27.491618858 * 27.491618858 = 755.789107434
div: 77.1000519162 / 31.1561128065 = 2.47463643475
div: 755.789107434 / 2.47463643475 = 305.414200171
div: 54.6298636339 / 77.1000519162 = 0.708558065477
add: 2708.41452689 + 0.708558065477 = 2709.12308496
sub: 2709.12308496 - 2708.41452689 = 0.708558065477
add: 305.414200171 + 0.708558065477 = 306.122758237
sub: 4 - 77.1000519162 = -73.1000519162
add: 306.122758237 + -73.1000519162 = 233.02270632
add: -10833.6581076 + 233.02270632 = -10600.6354013
sub: -10600.6354013 - 26.2235845341 = -10626.8589858
mul: 27.491618858 * 51.6965219541 = 1421.22107785
mul: 3.25991727261 * 54.6298636339 = 178.088836061
mul: 51.6965219541 * 178.088836061 = 9206.57342319
add: 1421.22107785 + 9206.57342319 = 10627.794501
add: -10626.8589858 + 10627.794501 = 0.935515251547
div: 51.6965219541 / 0.935515251547 = 55.2599456488
mul: 54.6298636339 * 55.2599456488 = 3018.84329521
sub: 103.393043908 - 3018.84329521 = -2915.4502513
add: 52.4471690682 + -2915.4502513 = -2863.00308224
add: 76.8309295836 + -2863.00308224 = -2786.17215265
-2786.17215265
230.629771452
```

Comment: Thanks @OrestHera, it did not occur to me to simply print what values the  operators are geting in order to decompose it. `ds` is the same as `data[17]`. `inputs['rv']` is getting changed somewhere when there is the update with the `locals()`, most probably because I have an rv variable set somewhere in the main module.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is then that the function has two poles wrt `rv`. Can you focus your answer on how one should deal with this? (just forget about the notebook nonsense) right now I am rounding d[-3] to int to try to avoid the issue (it is an assumption I can make) but I still find some solutions with the same issue.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, this function is basically an approximation of a method where we are using a taylor series for a complex derivation/integration of the cost function.

Comment: @rll Why do you think that the function should give a result in range `225...240`? The function has two major fractions where denominator is combined from input variables. So, the function can give any result basing on input. Is it possible that values of input `arglabels` are calculated incorrectly? BTW, you do not use the last two values in `d[0]` tuple: the 7 items are directly assigned to the variable and 8th and 9th are multiplied for `rv`. Do you consider print of `inputs` (actual values of `arglabels`) as a reasonable input?

Comment: Well, it should give something in that range for **this specific input set**, not for any inputs. It is based on the optimum being approximated (225), and on the result I obtained by solving the very same `fun` by hand (app. 241), so maybe the result is probably something in `205...245`. The values of the inputs are randomly generated based on variation from a specific case. The last two values are the targets, so they are not part of the inputs (they are just there because `d` is coming from a larger dataset). I did not get the last question though...

Comment: @rll As I understand the exact result should be in some range. Here the function is approximated. Since there are poles it looks like a Laurent series expansion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series However, see its convergence example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series#/media/File:Expinvsqlau_GIF.gif Only sum of the entire series can give good result. Low degree approximation can describe original function only in some limited range. Actaully, Taylor series approximation is also usable only in limited input range.

Comment: It is making sense now. The "issue" is with the function being approximated. The targets are extracted from the derivation of a a rather complex cost function; such derivation is only possible by using an approximation (in this case if I understood correctly they are using a 20th degree  taylor polynomial) which is like 2 or 3 A4 pages of polynomial expression. I guess the only way we have around this issue is to have more data points in the training set so that hopefully a better (tighter) approximation is reached.

Answer (score 1):

When I try your example, I get an answer of:

```
>>> print eval(fun, inputs)
-2786.17215265
```

If I use `gmpy2` and set the precision to 200 bits and the exponent range to ~1E9, I get an answer of:

```
>>> print eval(fun,inputs)
-2786.1721526580839894614784542009831125135156833413835128962432
```

It looks like the function is returning a stable result. So there is probably something wrong with the function.

I'd follow @Prune's advice and split the complex function into smaller steps.